# how to make a xlxs file as a blob

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am trying to load a xlsx file by clicking a button without using input . The file  "seedFile" is inside my project structure .The logic ran correct when I used a input but for internal files I am facing this issue and getting an err.

```
  var excelToJson =function (file) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var xlData = {};
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(seedFile);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                    type: 'binary'
                });

                 workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {
                    xlData[sheetName] = 
  XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                })

            };

            reader.onprogress = function (data) {
                if (data.lengthComputable) {
                    var progress = parseInt(((data.loaded / data.total) * 100), 10);
                    console.log(progress);
                }
            }
            reader.onerror = function (ex) {
                reject(ex);
            };
            reader.onloadend = function () {
                resolve(xlData)
            }
        })

    }
    var handleFiles = function (files) {
        var file = seedFile
        return excelToJson(file)
    }
    $("#seedFile").click(async () => {


    handleFiles(this.files).then(function success(data) {
        console.log(data);
        grid.setData(data.Sheet1).getInstance().loadData()
    }, function error(err) {
        alerts.error(err);
    })
   })
```

TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'. Is there any easy way to make the file as a blob internally ?

Comment: Where is `seedFile` coming from? The parameter seems to be `file`.

Comment: the seed file is inside the project structure like:  src/resources/seedFile.xlsx

Comment: Is this running on node.js or is this in a browser? If this in on a client machine, as far as I'm aware you cant read files on the users machine without an input selecting the file.

Comment: its running on node.js